# Horizontal Nested Draggable & Droppable (DND) React Component

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd, react-sortable-hoc

I am looking for nested horizontal  Draggable  & Droppable (DND) React Component something similar like this.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-sortable-js-nested-tu8nn
I even tried modifying the above using the props supported but it does not seem to work.
Any ideas or lead to achieve the same would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the codepen, add:

```
style={{display: 'flex'}}
```

to the `Container` component.